# vuejs vuetify carousel disappear when v-if is false

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've got very basic a carousel like below:

```
<v-carousel>
  <v-carousel-item
  v-for="(item,i) in carouselItems" 
  :key="i"
  v-if="item.person=='' || (item.person == person)"
  >
    <v-card-media  height="200px" :src="item.src">
    </v-card-media> 
  <v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

and the array that is the source of images:

```
carouselItems: [
  {
    src: require('@/assets/car1.jpeg'), person: '', value: '0'
  },
  {
    src: require('@/assets/car2.jpeg'), person: '', value: '1'
  },
  {
    src: require('@/assets/car3.jpeg'), person: 'physician', value: '2'
  },
  {
    src: require('@/assets/car4.jpeg'), person: 'nurse', value: '3'
  }
],
```

and od course select that I'm able to change the person: physician, nurse etc...

```
<v-select
:items="personItems"
v-model="person">
<v-select>

personItems: [
 { text: 'Physician', value: 'physician'},
 { text: 'Nurse', value: 'nurse', disabled: false },
],
```

I want to be able to choose between physician, nurse to change images which are available in my carousel (`''` - means that are available for all selects). And this is working fine, but I've got one problem. When I've got the carousel image choosen for examle `3` (`nurse`), and I switch my select to `physician` -> my carousel disapear.

I want it to switch to the first image on array that is for all or for physician. How can I fix my code to make it work?

Comment: Do you get any errors perhaps?

Comment: @Traxo No errors, I think that it is expected behavior when v-if is false - the item dissapear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a ref on  and then on the select's change event, select the first item in the carousel with `$refs.carousel.select(0)`.

```
<v-carousel ref="carousel">
  <v-carousel-item
  v-for="(item,i) in carouselItems" 
  :key="i"
  v-if="item.person=='' || (item.person == person)"
  >
    <v-card-media  height="200px" :src="item.src">
    </v-card-media> 
  <v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>


<v-select
:items="personItems"
v-model="person"
@change="$refs.carousel.select(0)">
<v-select>
```